# A synonym for Take somebody through

Tags: synonyms

Is there a synonym of the phrasal verb

> ***take somebody through something***

Here is the sentence I am working on:

> The director took us through the play scene by scene.

Comment: What exact ***meaning*** do you want to convey? [They will take him through trickery when he least expects it.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22take+him+through+trickery%22)

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use ***walk** [indirect object] **through***, which you obviously *do* know how to use? In fact, you could forget the ***us*** part, since it should be contextually obvious, so plain *He **went through** the play scene by scene* would be fine. You could say he ***walked/stepped*** you through it, for example, but I'm not convinced there's a single-word term with this precise meaning (especially, not one with any significant currency).

Comment: I'd like to know your motivation for seeking a synonym: Do you think it's too wordy? Phrasal verbs are often the most clear and natural way to express something. Putting all the debate about _went_ vs. _walk_ vs. _took_ aside, your original reads pretty good to me.

Comment: Because I am trying to translate it into Arabic and I can't find an equivalent  for it so I am trying to get a synonym to make it easier to get the Arabic equivalent @J.R.

Comment: You'd be better off making that part of your question rather than just as a comment to me. Generally speaking, the more you can tell us about **why** you are asking a question, the better your answers will be.

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker the phrase that I use most commonly in a situation like this is to "walk someone through"

Answer (score 1):

The closest synonym would be either "explain" or "describe" -- although as FumbleFingers points out, there is no single word which contains all the information as the idiomatic expression.

> One by one, the director *explained* each scene of the play to us.

Also as FumbleFingers mentions, the expression "walk us through" is somewhat more common than "take us through".